# Merging array of objects by different ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have such a case:

```
const ids = {
// id: parentId
  "2": "1",
  "3": "1"
}

const input = [
  {
    id: "1",
    data: [1],
  },
   {
     id: "2",
     data: [2]
   },
   {
     id: "3",
     data: [3]
   },
   {
     id: "4",
     data: [4]
   }
]

const output = [
  {
    id: "1",
    data: [1,2,3]
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    data: [4]
  }
]
```

With this ids I wanted to create some kind of config, which will determine which object in input array should have merged data (if there is no id-parentId pair defined, it should stay as it is). I belive code above is better explanation than this story. I tried with some mappings but without any nice result. This 'ids' array is an example, maybe there is a better way to define it so it will simplify the case? What do you think? I will be grateful for any hint

Comment: The ids seem to be hierarchical but the output is not. Why not just have mergeIds = [[1,2, 3], ...]?

Comment: you can't use `map()` if the output is a different size from the input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce()`. Create the output first as an object that uses `id` as the key. You can convert it to an array at the end with `Object.values()`.

```js
const ids = {
  // id: parentId
  "2": "1",
  "3": "1"
}

const input = [{
    id: "1",
    data: [1],
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    data: [2]
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    data: [3]
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    data: [4]
  }
]

const output = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, {
  id,
  data
}) => {
  if (id in ids) { // replace id with parent
    id = ids[id];
  }
  if (id in acc) {
    acc[id].data = acc[id].data.concat(data);
  } else {
    acc[id] = {
      id,
      data};
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the references for same groups.

```js
const
    ids = { 2: "1", 3: "1" },
    input = [{ id: "1", data: [1] }, { id: "2", data: [2] }, { id: "3", data: [3] }, { id: "4", data: [4] }],
    output = Object.values(input.reduce((r, { id, data }) => {
        id = ids[id] ?? id;
        (r[id] ??= { id, data: [] }).data.push(...data);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to cycle the input and modifying it in place, something like this should work:

```js
const input = [
  {
    id: '1',
    data: [1]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    data: [2]
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    data: [3]
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    data: [4]
  }
]

const config = {
  2: '1',
  3: '1'
}

const merge = ({ input, config } = {}) => {
  for (const [childId, parentId] of Object.entries(config)) {
    const childIndex = input.findIndex(i => i.id == childId)
    const parent = input.find(i => i.id == parentId)
    parent.data.push(...input[childIndex].data)
    input.splice(childIndex, 1)
  }

  return input
}

console.log(merge({ input, config }))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this:

```js
let ids = { 2: "1", 3: "1" }
let input = [{ id: "1", data: [1] }, { id: "2", data: [2] }, { id: "3", data: [3] }, { id: "4", data: [4] }];
let keys = Object.keys(ids);
let objs = input.slice();//in order to not mutate the source input
const output = objs.map(currObj=>{
    let currId = currObj.id;
    if(keys.includes(currId)){
        let changeObj = objs.find(obj=>obj.id==ids[currId])
        changeObj.data.push(...currObj.data)
    }
    return currObj
})
console.log(output);
```

*NOTE: I used slice() in order to not mutate the source input*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#reduce`, `Object.entries` and `Array#map` methods as follows:

```js
const ids = { "2": "1", "3": "1" },
      input = [ { id: "1", data: [1], }, { id: "2", data: [2] }, { id: "3", data: [3] }, { id: "4", data: [4] } ],

output = Object.entries(
    input.reduce(
        (acc,{id,data}) =>
        ids[id] ?
        ({...acc,[ids[id]]:[...(acc[ids[id]] || []),...data]}) :
        ({...acc,[id]:[...(acc[id] || []), ...data]}),{}
    )
)
.map(([id,data]) => ({id,data}));

console.log( output );
//OUTPUT: [{"id":"1","data":[1,2,3]},{"id":"4","data":[4]}]
```